# Bash while loop with options

Tags: bash, shell

So I have this code and it works fine when running: `script` and `script -n 1`.

But when running the script with option: 'script -n` it fails.

I would like to have the help option to pop up then.

Can someone help me?

```sh
    while [ -n "${1-}" ]; do
          case $1 in
            -n|--numb_of_times)
              num_of_times="$2"
              shift 2
              ;;
            -h|--help)
              help
              ;;
             *)
              help
              ;;
          esac
        done
```

Comment: Try `script -h`.

Comment: I know that works but I want "script -n" to generate help function, bc with -n option u shall need a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply modify the `-n` case:

```sh
case $1 in
  -n|--numb_of_times)
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
      help
    else
      num_of_times="$2"
      shift 2
    fi
    ;;
```

Or even better:

```sh
case $1 in
  -n|--numb_of_times)
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
      print 'missing number\n'
      help
    else
      num_of_times="$2"
      shift 2
    fi
    ;;
```